# After creating a sharepoint app project, there is no "default.aspx.cs" code behind file

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app

After creating a SharePoint app project, there is no "default.aspx.cs" code behind file. Only default.aspx

My APP is SharePoint-hosted. Is that the reason? Can I code freely in a SharePoint-hosted APP with C# code? If not, what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Can I code freely in a SharePoint-hosted APP with C# code?**

As short answer NO, `SharePoint hosted APP`is Written using JavaScript, HTML, and CSS , no Server Side code.

**If not, what is the best alternative?**

To can use Server side code you should use `Cloud-hosted APP`

- Provider-hosted
- Autohosted (is deprecated).

For more details check [Choose patterns for developing and hosting your SharePoint Add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179887%28v=office.15%29.aspx)